# kentico v9 page alias not working as expected

Tags: kentico

I have a repeater with a custom page type and two transformations. The first transformation list my custom pages in a table layout. My Selected Item Transformation uses the same template to show the page details. This section 'CEO Direct' sits within a node named Auxiliary Nav.

For example, this is the URL for a test: http://localhost:8080/Auxiliary-Nav/CEO-Direct/Questions/test.aspx

I was expecting it to be: http://localhost:8080/CEO-Direct/Questions/test.aspx

The Auxiliary Nav node has show navigation and site map unchecked.

This also affect my search results, so i'm hoping to kill two birds with one stone.

Here's a screen shot showing the URL and the breadcrumbs:

[image]

Comment: Localhost URLs only work for you local machine :) Do you have a screenshot or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh is correct, you need to write a macro that will pick the first Node Alias is present for the path.

Although writing a custom macro method may be cleaner and will allow you to re-use, you can use the following macro for the time being:

{% ( CurrentDocument.Aliases.Count > 0 ? CurrentDocument.Aliases.FirstItem.AliasURLPath : CurrentDocument.RelativeURL) #%}

Note that the above will just grab the first path, there isn't really Alias Ordering so if you put more than 1, it will probably grab the most recent.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the getdocumenturl macro for the url?  if so, you need to change it out to be the alias or change the path to a custom path and then getdocumenturl will work.

Comment: No, i'm just using the out of the box functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think in need to rethink my node structure and auxiliary nav implementation. It looks like i need to move these section to the root level, hide them from navigation, and adjust my .master page with link buttons for what i need here.

This should solve my URL and search alias issues.